# Переопределить метод

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ребят, пытаюсь разобраться с наследованием и не могу понять, как переопределить метод `get_extra_mony()` из родительского классаStudent в наследуемом классе `Warden()`.

Что нужно сделать, чтобы дописать в этот метод простенький `print()`? Пытался начать с переопределения `__init__` в классе Warden вот так: `Student.__init__(self,extra_mony)`.

Пайчарм переменную extra_mony подчеркивает красным и
пишет ошибку `AttributeError: 'Warden' object has no attribute 'extra_mony'.` В других источниках пишут, что использовать нужно метод `super()`.

```
class Student():

    def __init__(self,extra_mony):

        self.extra_mony = extra_mony
        self.tax = 5

    def set_extra_mony(self,extra_mony):
         self.extra_mony = extra_mony

    def set_tax(self,tax):
         self.tax = tax

    def get_tax(self):
         return self.tax

    def get_extra_mony(self):

        my_tax = self.extra_mony / 100

        finnaly_tax = my_tax*self.tax
        print('cтепендия минус налог:',self.extra_mony- 
        finnaly_tax,'грн')

        return self.extra_mony - finnaly_tax

class Warden(Student):

    def __init__(self,count_people):

        self.count_people = count_people
        Student.__init__(self,extra_mony)
```

Comment: "Mony" - точно то, что вы имели ввиду?

Comment: наверное все таки 'many'))

Comment: @Jeniakv, я, конечно, не полиглот, но, наверное, всё-таки "money". =)

Comment: Ну начнём с того, что в вашем Warden и правда неоткуда взяться переменной extra_mony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Накидал пример, попробуйте:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,extra_mony):
        self.extra_mony = extra_mony
        self.tax = 5

    def set_extra_mony(self,extra_mony):
         self.extra_mony = extra_mony

    def set_tax(self,tax):
         self.tax = tax

    def get_tax(self):
         return self.tax

    def get_extra_mony(self):
        my_tax = self.extra_mony / 100

        finnaly_tax = my_tax*self.tax
        print('cтепендия минус налог:',self.extra_mony-finnaly_tax,'грн')

        return self.extra_mony - finnaly_tax


class Warden(Student):
    # В конструкторе Student передается extra_mony
    def __init__(self, count_people, extra_mony):
        super().__init__(extra_mony)
        
        self.count_people = count_people
    
    # Переопределенный метод
    def get_extra_mony(self):
        # Вызов родительского метода
        value = super().get_extra_mony()
        print("get_extra_mony ->", value)

        return value
```